# dart import and part of directives in same file

Tags: import, dart

I'm writing a dart file:

```
import 'something.dart'

part of my_lib;

class A{
    //...
}
```

I have tried this with the `import` and `part of` directives reversed and it still won't work, can you not have a class file as part of a library and have imports?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All your imports should go in the file that defines the library.

Library:

```
library my_lib;

import 'something.dart';

part 'a.dart';

class MyLib {
  //...
}
```

a.dart

```dart
part of my_lib;

class A {
  //...
}
```

Since a.dart is part of my_lib it will have access to any files that my_lib imports.

Answer (score 4):

The Pixel Elephanr's answer is correct, but I suggest the **alternative syntax for the part-of directive**:

my_file.dart
(the library main file):

```dart
//This now is optional:
//library my_lib; 

import 'something.dart';

part 'a.dart';

class MyLib {
  //...
}
```

a.dart
(part of the same library; so in it you can reference the elements imported in my_file.dart)

```dart
//Instead of this (whitout quotes, and referencing the library name):
//part of my_lib;

//use this (whit quotes, and referencing the library file path): 
part of 'my_file.dart'

class A {
  //...
}
```

In the Doc you can found both the syntax, but only using the part-of's syntax **with quotes** (pointing to the file path), **you can omit the library directive** in the library main file; or, if the library directive is still needed for other reasons (to put doc and annotations to library level), at least you won't be forced to keep in sync the library name in multiple files, which is boring in case of refactoring.

Comment: The Dart team has introduced a new lint rule [`use_string_in_part_of_directives`](https://dart.dev/effective-dart/usage#do-use-strings-in-part-of-directives). So declaring `part of library_name;` is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this in IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio while moving the files via drag and drop, then switch to 'Project Source' in project pane at left and then move(drag and drop). When I faced this problem while working with flutter, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

place all your files where you define your library
like i defined **branch_cubit** and all my imports are there
and in the **branch_state** i added par of keyword in the branch_state