# How to get the value of a var of another file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, var

I am trying to get the val of a var in a different file in flutter, I tried to do something like this : `New x = New();  'New is my class', x.variable = ...`

This didn't work for me. Any ideas how I can make something like this work?

```
import 'auth/LoginPage.dart' as login;

class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomePageState createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();
  var x = login.userType;
```

Comment: Try making it a global variable in file.

Comment: How do I do that

Answer (score 0):

So you need to create a file **login.dart** from where you want to import methods like this:

```
//login.dart

enum UserType { Firebase, Google, Twitter }

getUserTypeFirebase() {
  return UserType.Firebase;
}

getUserTypeGoogle() {
  return UserType.Google;
}

getUserTypeTwitter() {
  return UserType.Twitter;
}
```

Then you create the library **login_lib.dart** using the `library` statement and `export` statement to export other files or packages that you want to use from this library. In this case we export the file **login.dart** like described bellow.

```
//login_lib.dart

library login;

export 'login.dart';
```

And after that you can import the login_lib in the class you want like this:

```
//welcome_page.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login_lib.dart' as login;

class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  var x = login.getUserTypeGoogle();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Is it possible to use shared preferences in this ?

Comment: After you added some code in the question, i think that maybe you need to add an `export` statement in the class from where you can get some variable/method. I believe the discussions in these posts can be what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480039/dart-need-explanation-of-library-part-and-import-export and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763378/when-to-use-part-part-of-versus-import-export-in-dart

Comment: But how can I use export here because I have no experience in it :(

Comment: I don't know exactly you want to do. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, maybe there's another ways, that can be pretty simple to implement than that. But I edited my answer. Take a look to see if solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do autologin but when I tried it it gave an error,Is there sth wrong? CODE :

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then(
      (res) async {
        print(userType);
        if (res != null && userType == 'Admin') {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/AdminPage');
        }
        if (res != null && userType == 'Student') {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/StudentPage');
        }
        if (res != null && userType == 'Teacher') {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/TeacherPage');
        }
```

It says userType is null, so My new question is about the capability of using a var outside of initState inside it ? Confused Right ?

Answer (score 0):

**The file i want the value from :**

***importme.dart***

- Remove the _  from the extended part...
- Make the variable static ..

> class MultiSelectChip extends StatefulWidget {   final List
> reportList;   final Function(List) onSelectionChanged;
>
> **_MultiSelectChip**(this.reportList, {required
> this.onSelectionChanged});
>
> @override   **_**MultiSelectChipState createState() =>
> MultiSelectChipState(); }
>
> class **_MultiSelectChipState** extends State {
> **static List selectedChoices =
> [];**

***mainfile.dart***

> import 'package:ytsubmeapp/widgets/multichoice.dart';
>
> List x = MultiSelectChipState.selectedChoices;